# Variant on Law of Iterated Conditioning

Tags: probability

By the law of Iterated Conditioning, we know it is true that for sigma-algebras G and H, with $H\subseteq G$ it follows that $E[E[XY|G]|H] = E[XY|H]$ for random variables X, Y on $(\Omega, H, G)$.

Does this also hold: $E[XE[Y|G]|H] = E[XY|H]$?

Comment: I have no idea why I was down voted on this question. Please leave feedback if you down vote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: No.

Let $\Omega = \{-1,1\}$, $X = Y = {\mathrm{id}}\colon \Omega \to \mathbf R$ and $G = H = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, $\mathbf P$ the uniform distribution on $\Omega$, that is $\frac 12(\delta_{1} + \delta_{-1})$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  \def\E{\mathbf E} \E[Y\mid G] &= 0\\
                   X\E[Y \mid G] &= 0\\
                  \E[X\E[Y\mid G] \mid H] &= 0\\
\text{but }      XY &= 1\\
              \E[XY \mid H] &= 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I realized what I need is that X be G measurable, then I can pull X inside and be left with E[E[XY|G]|H] which is the ordinary form of iterated conditioning. So, my result I need still holds.